Soldering fixable?
noob question… So I desoldered 2 wires and ended up removing the solder points as well. Is there any way I can resolder new wires to these 2 terminals?

You've removed the pads, so it is not possible to solder back onto them directly.
Instead you'll need to glue down whatever component you are replacing, and then either bend the pins of the component if possible or run small wires from the pins to alternate places on the PCB where the pads are routed to.

I've circled in Red (right) and Blue (left) the areas where the two pads connect. You should be able to remove the soldermask with a small flat head screwdriver (gentle scraping action should chip it off), then tin the exposed copper with solder (liberal application of flux can help here).
I've also circled in Green what appears to be a solder blob shorting two components. Make sure to remove this solder blob if they are not supposed to be connected (it looks like a PCB trace connects them anyway, but I can't tell for sure).

"with a small flat head screwdriver" Or use the right tools: a scalpel or other such small precision knife.

@Lundin "Or use the right tool" - a small flat head screwdriver is what I've always used, and works extremely effectively. It's very easy to damage the copper traces with a scalpel, whilst a very thin jewelers screwdriver removes the soldermask whilst doing minimal damage to the copper trace beneath.

You'd use it to scrape, not to cut, or it is indeed very easy to damage. Similar to using a razor when shaving :) But well, I suppose "screwdriver" is actually a very wide range of tools.

@Lundin I suppose, though using a scalpel to scrape is a very good way to stop it being a scalpel (break off the tip/blunten it).

Indeed, you'll need to change them quite often when used for PCB rework.

Yes there is. But you'll need to be careful. If you know which traces these are connected to, you can use a small knife or something similar to scratch away the solder resist/mask. Then get some flux onto the bare copper, and get a small blob of solder on there, then you just solder the wires to the solder blobs.
